# Count Query not returning the same result as identical query

Tags: mysql

I have the two following queries. One is to get the actual data and the other is to count how many results there are in total as I am using code igniter's pagination to break up the results. Why are these different and how can I make sure they return the same number of results?

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t`.`TermID`, `t`.`Definition`, `t`.`Name` FROM `term` AS `t` 
JOIN `syllabusin` AS `si` ON `t`.`TermID` = `si`.`TermID` 
JOIN `synonyms` AS `sy` ON `t`.`TermID` = `sy`.`TermID` 
WHERE (`si`.`SyllabusID` = 7 
    OR `si`.`SyllabusID` = 6  ) 
AND (`t`.`Name` LIKE '%portability testing%' 
  OR `t`.`Acronym` LIKE '%portability testing%' 
  OR `t`.`Definition` LIKE '%portability testing%' ) 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(*) as count FROM `term` AS `t` 
JOIN `syllabusin` AS `si` ON `t`.`TermID` = `si`.`TermID` 
JOIN `synonyms` AS `sy` ON `t`.`TermID` = `sy`.`TermID` 
WHERE (`si`.`SyllabusID` = 7 
    OR `si`.`SyllabusID` = 6 ) 
AND (`t`.`Name` LIKE '%portability testing%' 
  OR `t`.`Acronym` LIKE '%portability testing%' 
  OR `t`.`Definition` LIKE '%portability testing%' )
```

As you will be able to see the only differences are the 'LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0' and the COUNT(*)

Comment: I just deleted my answer... I realised there's actually no question asked here at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;` is very different from `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;`

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT `t`.`TermID`, `t`.`Definition`, `t`.`Name`) as count FROM `term` AS `t` ...
```

instead of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(*) as count FROM `term` AS `t` ...
```

Hope it's useful!

Comment: @Nicholas: Happy for u:)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Count(*) as count FROM `term` AS `t`
```

should be

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT `t`.`TermID`) as count FROM `term` AS `t`
```

Comment: This did work too but the other answer explains it slightly better.

Answer (score 0):

The distinct helps in getting the distinct rows and distinct values in the column......  the 1st query is finding out the distinct values of the column termID, Definition, name in the rows of the table and showing them........... whereas the second query is using count function with distinct which is counting the number of distinct rows that are present in the table.... so these two queries seem to be same but are generating two different values................................